Origin of terms Harrod neutral, Solow neutral and Hicks neutral
I just looked for the same question on the exchange but I didn't find anything, I even tried to look for the answer on Google but it seems it's not present. Could someone give me the origin of these three important expressions? From the Introduction to Modern Economic Growth I saw that Hicks neutral comes from Hicks but the other two?
